# insert query is not working for the row which has a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to learn foreign key constraint so far i have been able to create foreign keys in mysql

Here is my create table query for three tables:

```
create table customer(
CustId int(100) not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
FirstName varchar(300) default null,
LastName varchar(300) default null,
Gender varchar(200) default null,
Category varchar(200) default null,
DateOfBirth varchar(200) default null,
Age int(3)default null
);

create table address(
Address_Id int(100) not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
Address varchar(1000) default null,
Country varchar(500) default null,
State varchar (500) default null,
city varchar(500)default null,
PinCode int(10)default null,
CustId int(100) not null,
foreign key(CustId) references customer(CustId)
);

create table contact(
Contact_Id int(100) not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
EmailId varchar(500)default null,
ContactNo varchar(20) default null,
MobileNo varchar(20) default null,
CustId int(100) not null,
Address_Id int(100) not null,
foreign key(CustId) references customer(CustId),
foreign key(Address_Id) references address(Address_Id)
);
```

**K now i got it till here :**

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET @lid := null;

insert into customer (FirstName,LastName,Gender,Category,DateOfBirth,Age)values('Ashok','sharma','Male','Affiliate','1988-04-17','26');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @lid; 
insert into address(CustId, Address,Country,State,city,Pincode)values (@lid, 'No.1645','India','Karnataka','Bangalore','560060');
COMMIT;
```

Using transaction and commit was the solution but how to do it for contact table where i have too foreign keys. And i need to get two auto incremented values.

Please guide me on this as well.

Comment: Are you asking how to obtain the value of the last AUTO_INCREMENT? That's in fact unrelated to foreign keys.

Comment: Either you have to use multiple queries to update multiple tables or you can use stored procedures to do the same. In this case you just have to call the stored procedure.

Comment: @Zodaix `insert into address(Address,Country,State,city,Pincode)values ('No.1645','India','Karnataka','Bangalore','560060');
insert into contact(CustId)select CustId from customer;` I did it like this but the id field is incremented again and then the 2nd insert statement is getting executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this in multiple statements:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET @lid := null;

insert into customer (FirstName,LastName,Gender,Category,DateOfBirth,Age)values('Ashok','sharma','Male','Affiliate','1988-04-17','26');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @lid; 
insert into address(CustId, Address,Country,State,city,Pincode)values (@lid, 'No.1645','India','Karnataka','Bangalore','560060');
COMMIT;
```

> For MySQL 5.1.12 and later, with no argument, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a 64-bit value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement.

This is session bound, so don't worry, that another session messes up your last_insert_id or something. Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

And you better put it all in a transaction like I did. This makes sure, that all statements succeed or none, not just parts of them. You have to use InnoDB for it though. MyISAM does not support this. Or you live with the risk :) But since you use foreign keys I assume you use InnoDB, just wanted to mention it for completeness.

The variable I used can of course be replaced with a PHP variable. Or you do it like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;

insert into customer (FirstName,LastName,Gender,Category,DateOfBirth,Age)values('Ashok','sharma','Male','Affiliate','1988-04-17','26');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @lid; 
insert into address(CustId, Address,Country,State,city,Pincode)
SELECT @lid, 'No.1645','India','Karnataka','Bangalore','560060';
COMMIT;
```

**EDIT:**

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET @lid_c := null;
SET @lid_a := null;

insert into customer (FirstName,LastName,Gender,Category,DateOfBirth,Age)values('Ashok','sharma','Male','Affiliate','1988-04-17','26');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @lid_c; 
insert into address(CustId, Address,Country,State,city,Pincode)values (@lid, 'No.1645','India','Karnataka','Bangalore','560060');

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @lid_a; 
INSERT INTO contact (CustId, Address_Id, another_column) VALUES
(@lid_c, @lid_a, 'another_value');

COMMIT;
```

Comment: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @lid;`  can u please explain this line?

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` checks the table for the last row that was inserted and gets its `id`. Here it checks its id count and then inserts in the next table where that `id` acts as a foreign key

Comment: now how to do it for contact table where it has two foreign keys CustId and AddressId form tables customer and Address respectively...

Comment: @fancyPants and a last question should lid be placed at the first in the insert column cos i wrote it in the last it was no taking so asked

Comment: You have to match the values to the columns of course. When you specify `CustId` last in the `insert into` line, you have to specify it last in the `values` line.

Comment: k thank u for answering all my questions thanks a lot

Comment: @fancyPants and i was not able to give the variable name as lid1 and lid2 its throwing an error

Comment: What is the error? Are you executing this via PHP? Is the error, that you want to execute multiple statements in one?

Comment: hey is this concept present in java environment??

Comment: I'm no Java guy, but I'd bet on it.

Comment: ya this works fine with java as well i checked thanks a lot for helping me out again